# Why does my binary response add spaces between characters?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, binary, knex.js

I'm using Node, Express, KNEX, and the tedious drivers to interface with SQL Server.  I execute a stored procedure which returns a `varbinary(max)` response.  I cannot alter this stored procedure.

When I capture the response and attempt to convert it to a string, which will be sent back to the browser, the expected response has a ton of white space characters between each character.

What I am doing wrong?

```
        // const { StringDecoder } = require('string_decoder');
        // const decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

        const response = await Webservice.spWebservice(params)  //exec stored procedure
        let { Response_Binary } = response;

        console.log(Response_Binary)

        const buff = Buffer.from(Response_Binary)
        console.log(buff);
        console.log(buff.toString());


        // console.log(decoder.write(buff));
        // console.log(decoder.end(buff));
```

**Actual SQL Server response (via KNEX):**

`<Buffer 3c 00 3f 00 78 00 6d 00 6c 00 20 00 76 00 65 00 72 00 73 00 69 00 6f 00 6e 00 3d 00 22 00 31 00 2e 00 30 00 22 00 20 00 65 00 6e 00 63 00 6f 00 64 00 ... 764 more bytes>`

**`Buffer.from()`**

`<Buffer 3c 00 3f 00 78 00 6d 00 6c 00 20 00 76 00 65 00 72 00 73 00 69 00 6f 00 6e 00 3d 00 22 00 31 00 2e 00 30 00 22 00 20 00 65 00 6e 00 63 00 6f 00 64 00 ... 764 more bytes>`

**`toString()`**

`< ? x m l   v e r s i o n = " 1 . 0 "   e n c o d i n g = " U T F - 1 6 " ? > < x m l > < s t a t u s > < r e s u l t > S u c c e s s < / r e s u l t > < m e s s a g e > < / m e s s a g e > < / s t a t u s > < d a t a > <   p p A c t i o n > i n i t < / A p p A c t i o n > < U s e r I n f o > < U s e r >  < / U s e r > < A d d r e s s > : : 1 < / A d d r e s s > < U s e r A g e n t > M o z i l l a / 5 . 0   ( W i n d o w s   N T     0 . 0 ;   W i n 6 4 ;   x 6 4 )   A p p l e W e b K i t / 5 3 7 . 3 6   ( K H T M L ,   l i k e   G e c k o )   C h r o m e / 9 2 . 0 . 4 5 1 5 . 1 3 1   S a f a r i / 5 3 7 . 3 6 < / U s e r A g e n t > < C a l l e r > <   C a l l e r > < R e f e r r e r > < / R e f e r r e r > < O p t i o n s > < / O p t i o n s > < / U s e r I n f o > < / d a t a > < / x m l >`
`

**Things I have tried [updated]:**

```
        let convertedBuffer = Buffer.from(Response_Binary, 'binary').toString();
        console.log(convertedBuffer) // extra spaces between characters

        convertedBuffer = Buffer.from(Response_Binary, 'ascii').toString();
        console.log(convertedBuffer) // extra spaces between characters
        
        convertedBuffer = Buffer.from(Response_Binary, 'utf-8').toString();
        console.log(convertedBuffer) // extra spaces between characters
        
        convertedBuffer = Buffer.from(Response_Binary, 'utf8').toString();
        console.log(convertedBuffer) // extra spaces between characters
        
        convertedBuffer = Buffer.from(Response_Binary, 'base64').toString();
        console.log(convertedBuffer) // extra spaces between characters
        
        convertedBuffer = Buffer.from(Response_Binary, 'utf16le').toString();
        console.log(convertedBuffer) // extra spaces between characters


        console.log(`Is Response_Binary from KNEX/MSSQL actually a buffer? ===>>> `)
        console.log(Buffer.isBuffer(Response_Binary)); // returns true;


        console.log(Response_Binary.toString('ascii'));   // extra spaces between characters
        console.log(Response_Binary.toString('utf-8'));   // extra spaces between characters
        console.log(Response_Binary.toString('utf8'));    // extra spaces between characters
        console.log(Response_Binary.toString('base64'));  // not for humans
        console.log(Response_Binary.toString('utf16le')); // CORRECT ANSWER!!!!!
```

`Response_Binary.toString('utf16le')` returns:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><xml><status><result>Success</result><message></message></status><data><AppAction>init</AppAction><UserInfo><User>redacted</User><Address>::1</Address><UserAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT  10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36</UserAgent><Caller></Caller><Referrer></Referrer><Options></Options></UserInfo></data></xml>`

Comment: One might ask why you are storing string data as `varbinary`?

Comment: I'm attempting to transition away from a Java Servlet (Tomcat) to Node.  The designer of the Stored Procedure, my Boss, sends binary from SQL to Tomcat, so I want to learn how to properly decode the binary response.  He reported that text from SQL was really slow, and binary was faster.  The world has changed a lot in 20 years, and I may be able to negotiate with him, but I'd like to try and keep the master stored procedure unmodified, to whatever extent possible.

Comment: Seems you have unicode characters stored in your binary column. You write that you "played around with encoding - so exactly how? The default is utf8 which does not seem correct. What encoding values did you try?

Comment: That looks like UTF-16 little-endian to me.

Comment: Folks:  I used your commentary as inspiration.  I have updated the "What I have tried section".  Turns out, the only way I personally could get this to work was with this: `Response_Binary.toString('utf16le')` .  I looked on Microsoft's website for how `varbinary(max)` is encoded, but I couldn't find an answer.  So, I suppose my REAL question must be:  How am I supposed to know in what way `varbinary(max)` is encoded?

Comment: Sooooo......  that was slow.....  this is faster:  `res.end(Response_Binary, 'binary');`  I'm going to need to read up on why.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, but I will accept any better explanation:

I theorize that TSQL's default character encoding for `vabinary(max)` is `utf16le`.

`KNEX` returns TSQL's binary response as a ready-to-go Buffer.  `Buffer.isBuffer(Response_Binary) //it's a buffer!`

This means I can call Buffer's `.toString()` directly on `Response_Binary`:

`Response_Binary.toString('utf16le')`

I would like to note that I'm sending a response to the browser, and the approach above is SLOW.  Looking through my notes, I discovered that not only is `res.end()` WAY faster, it also "converts" it:

**SLOW * :**

```
     strXML = Response_Binary.toString('utf16le');
     return res.send(strXML);
```

**FAST * :**

```
     return res.end(Response_Binary, 'binary');
```

source inspiration:  https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/06/17/knex-postgresql-blobs/

**===== [UPDATE] SLOW VS FAST: =====**

After further testing, I cannot tell a discernable difference between these two approaches.